# VB Environment for a beginner

Tags: vb.net

I am fairly new to programming, and I would like to start programming.  I have heard that visual basic is good, and would like to know a good environment to start with.  Any ideas on where to start? Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome!

I think you will be able to find what you need on the Microsoft site, since they created VB.  I also believe its a free download.  I started with Java, but VB would probably be nicer.

Heres the link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ms788232.aspx

EDIT:

I didn't realize in your question you tagged VB.net, heres the link for that:

http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-basic-express

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start programming in VB.Net, you might want to check Visual Studio...

here's the link to the express version : http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-basic-express